# How to pass an async function as a parameter in Rust PyO3

Tags: python, asynchronous, rust, async-await, pyo3

When we write vanilla rust and we have to pass in an async function as an argument to another function we do the following:

```
pub f<F,'a>(
    test: &dyn Fn(&'a mut String, String, String, TcpStream) -> F,
) where
    F: Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
```

But when I do the same on a `#![pyfunction]` expecting to get an async **python** function, I am getting an error.

```
e.g async def fn():
            ....
```

On reading the docs of PyO3, I found out that I can include `PyAny` as a param.

But, on implementing the following function:

```
pub fn start_server(test: PyAny) {
  test.call0();
}
```

I get the following error.

```
[rustc E0277] [E] the trait bound `pyo3::PyAny: pyo3::FromPyObject<'_>` is not satisfied

expected an implementor of trait `pyo3::FromPyObject<'_>`

note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `pyo3::FromPyObject<'_>` for `pyo3::PyAny`
```

How can I implement this in my code. I would understand if this is not possible , if that is the case, I would request you to please recommend me an alternative.

UPDATE:

I have found an alternative where I create an empty struct and call the method in the following way. But I would really appreciate if I can get through without creating an empty struct.

```
#[pymethods]
impl Server {
    #[new]
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }

    fn start(mut self_: PyRefMut<Self>, test: &PyAny) {
        test.call0();
    }
}
```

But on passing an async function as param gives an error of

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine
  s.start(h)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more information and the exact error, otherwise people won't be able to provide help. See this explanation of a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @sebpuetz, I have made some additions. Do let me know if any more info is required from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs to take a reference, i.e. `&PyAny`. `PyAny` as an owned value does not implement `FromPyObject`, which is why you got the error.

```
// lib.rs
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::wrap_pyfunction;

#[pyfunction]
fn foo(x: &PyAny) -> PyResult<&PyAny> {
    x.call0()
}

#[pymodule]
fn async_pyo3(py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(foo, m)?).unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

```
import async_pyo3

async def bar():
    return "foo"

awaitable = async_pyo3.foo(bar) # <coroutine object bar at 0x7f8f6aa01340>
print(await awaitable) # "foo"
```

As such, the fix of moving it to an method on `Server` most likely was not the fix, but just coincidence since you changed `test` to `&PyAny`.

There is [a whole section in the PyO3 documentation](https://pyo3.rs/v0.13.2/ecosystem/async-await.html) about integrating Python and Rust async / await

Comment: even changing it to &PyAny did not fix it and is giving out the same error.

Comment: It works for me locally, I'll edit my answer to include the full Python & Rust code.